# Posting comment on facebook from 30th April 2015

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi I have application built-in c# and i am using facebook.dll for posting comment on facebook post. As facebook will going to change their api on 30th April 2015, what all changes do I need to make in my code or where I will get updated facebook.dll compatible with version publishing on 30th April 2015?

Comment: I think part of your question might be where to get a Facebook.dll that support versioned service calls, which I asked about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458334/how-to-call-versioned-graph-api-services-in-facebook-net-sdk

Comment: What platform does your app run on?