# How to call versioned graph API services in Facebook .NET SDK?

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

It seems that Facebook now [wants us to call versioned endpoints](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v1tov2) of the Graph API. E.g., https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me...

Does the [Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/) make versioned calls? Do I/can I do something to specify the version?

Comment: Yes it is. Look at the following commit: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/commit/c984c635af1bc5cbdb65f2221cff9d735d394912. This is present in the v7.0.1-alpha version of the nuget (install-package Facebook -pre).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sanjeev got it, there is a parameter you can add to specify version:

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient();
fbClient.Version = "v2.2";
fbClient.Post("me/feed", new
{
    message = string.Format("Hello version 2.2! - Try #2"),
    access_token = "youraccesstokenhere"
});
```

If you are not specifying a version, it'll default to the oldest supported version:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#unversioned_calls

Facebook will warn you that you are nearing end of support for that version.

Don't take any chances that the auto-upgrade to newer version will work, better to develop, test and deliver with the latest version.