# Facebook SDK for .NET - Specify Graph 2.0+ in API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook SDK for .NET, how do I specify the version of the Facebook Graph API that I want to use?  (Or at the very least, tell which version it is using by default?)

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter you can add to specify version:

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient();
fbClient.Version = "v2.2";
fbClient.Post("me/feed", new
{
    message = string.Format("Hello version 2.2! - Try #2"),
    access_token = "youraccesstokenhere"
});
```

More info over here:
[How to call versioned graph API services in Facebook .NET SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458334/how-to-call-versioned-graph-api-services-in-facebook-net-sdk)